# $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Fix $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathbb{F}_{r}=\langle g_{1}, ...,g_{r}\rangle$ be the rank-r free group. Then,

> How to prove $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{3}$? (Or maybe you can give me a reference where i can find this prove.)

Comment: Your edit makes this a *completely* different question than the one you started with. Please ask it as a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: @Mike Miller Ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the answer by Martin Brandenburg, but expanded and more clearly explained in the concrete context. You need to prove that the subgroup $\left<g_1,g_2\right>$ of $\mathbb{F}_3$ satisfies the universal property required for a $2$-generator free group. So, take any group $G$ and any map $f:\{g_1,g_2\}\to G$. You need to show that there exists a morphism $\bar f:\left<g_1,g_2\right>\to G$ such that $\bar f(g_i)=f(g_i)$ for $i=1,2$. Now take any map $\phi:\{g_1,g_2,g_3\}\to G$ which extends $f$, that is, for which $\phi\vert_{\{g_1,g_2\}}= f$ (simply by defining $\phi(g_i):=f(g_i)$ for $i=1,2$ and setting $\phi(g_3):=1$, for example). By the universal property of $\mathbb{F}_3$, there exists a morphism $\bar \phi:\mathbb{F_3}\to G$ for which $\bar\phi(g_i)=\phi(g_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$. Now you may restrict the morphism $\bar\phi$ to $\left<g_1,g_2\right>$ and denote this restriction $h:=\bar\phi\vert_{\left<g_1,g_2\right>}$. So you have a morphism $h:\left<g_1,g_2\right>\to G$ which satisfies, for $i=1,2$, $h(g_i)=\bar\phi(g_i)=\phi(g_i)=f(g_i)$. So, $\bar f:=h$ has the property needed.

By an analogous argument, whenever $X\subseteq Y$ then $F(X)\cong \left<X\right>\subseteq F(Y)$ where $F(Z)$ is the free group on $Z$. The same is actually true for free algebras in a variety (in the sense of universal algebra).

Comment: What does your first paragraph want to show? $F(X)\cong \langle X\rangle$??

Comment: @Yan: The first paragraph shows that the subgroup $\left< g_1,g_2\right>$ of $\mathbb{F}_3$ generated by the first two of its three free generators $g_1,g_2,g_3$ enjoys the universal property with respect to the generating set $\{g_1,g_2\}$ required from a free group **and therefore is isomorphic with** $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I,J$ be two sets; assume that $I$ is non-empty. Let $f : I \to J$ be an injective map. Then $f$ as a section $J \to I$: on $\mathrm{im}(f)$ it's clear what to do, and the rest is mapped to some fixed element of $I$. The universal property (or just the functoriality) of free groups implies that $f$ induces a homomorphism of groups $F(I) \to F(J)$ which has a section. Therefore, it is injective, i.e. may be considered as a subgroup.

Comment: I think this is not really helpful for someone who is asking this question. So I tried to adjust to the level of understanding.